# Software Architecture training resources

Tags: architecture

What are the best resources to properly establish oneself in best Software Architecture practices.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not so sure that being a software architect is something you "train" for as much as it is something you must acquire experience with. Still, if you're persistent about this, I'd be glad to share my recipe.

#### Recipe for perfect software architect

- 7+ years of diverse experience; more is definitely better
- Active professional involvement in the local and broader technical community
- Practiced and well-honed communication skills so that you can express your ideas to technical and non-technical staff
- Ability to be effective as a leader and mentor

Mix ingredients in enterprise-class bowl. Serves 1 to N.

Comment: I think I'd argue that's the recipe for a technical team lead, what Fred Brooks would call a "director.  My own opinion is that "architect" is about nonfunctional requirements.

Comment: Fair enough -- but that's why I made this a wiki! Perhaps the community can converge on a definition of "architect".

Comment: John your checklist is exactly what was troubling me. Even with most of those, I still think there is some formal requirement that I still need to really step into a role that I have been playing for a while. 

I don't think the answer precludes its application to non-functional requirements though.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a nice little list [10 Papers Every Software Architect Should Read](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/10-papers-every-software-architect-shoul/228700494) if you're looking for some reading material. The "Big Ball Of Mud" paper is a particular favourite of mine.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of really good stuff at the http://www.infoQ.com architecture  site.

Martin Fowler's site is good too.